# How can I rename the list of button operators

Tags: python

I want to rename buttons in my panel by index

[image]

```
import bpy
 
 
class ADDONNAME_PT_main_panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Main Panel"
    bl_idname = "ADDONNAME_PT_main_panel"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = "New Tab"
 
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scene = context.scene
        mytool = scene.my_tool
 
        obj = context.object
        

        row = layout.row()

        for x in range(0,10):
            row.operator("addonname.myop_operator")
            row = layout.row()
            
 
 
class ADDONNAME_OT_my_op(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_label = "Operator"
    bl_idname = "addonname.myop_operator"
    
    
    def execute(self, context):
        scene = context.scene
        mytool = scene.my_tool
        return {'FINISHED'}
    
          
classes = [ADDONNAME_PT_main_panel, ADDONNAME_OT_my_op]
 
 
def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls) 
       
 
def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)
        del bpy.types.Scene.my_tool

 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docs: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.UILayout.html#bpy.types.UILayout.operator
`row.operator("addonname.myop_operator", text=str(x + 1))`